# How can I install and enable this theme?

Tags: package, themes

I have been using this solarized theme for many years now: https://github.com/sellout/emacs-color-theme-solarized. This theme used to be available in the MELPA repos, but it is no longer available there.

I always run emacs in my terminal with `emacs -nw` and I am currently using `GNU Emacs 27.2`.

My problem is that I am currently moving to a fresh linux install, and want to continue to use this theme. What is the "correct" way to install this package manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming you want to install the theme in `~/.emacs.d/lisp/emacs-color-theme-solarized`.)

The first step would be to clone the repository:

```
$ cd ~/.emacs.d/lisp
$ git clone 'https://github.com/sellout/emacs-color-theme-solarized.git'
```

Then to add this path to `custom-theme-load-path` by modifying your `init.el` with something along the lines of:

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path
             (file-name-as-directory
              (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/lisp/emacs-color-theme-solarized")))
```

And then it’s business as usual:

```
(load-theme 'solarized t)
```

Comment: Very nice. Thank you!